# Advantages of categorizing objects into folders named as the first 2 characters of SHA-1 string?

Tags: git

Git stores objects into categorized folders using the first 2 characters of the object's SHA-1 string, what's the advantage of this storage structure?

I think it cannot avoid any potential conflict, why not put all the objects into a flat folder?

Comment: I have rewritten [my answer below](http://stackoverflow.com/a/30663224/6309)

Answer (score 6):

That **loose objects** structure ([example here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5710039/6309), and in [Git Internal - Packfiles](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Internals-Packfiles)) represents how the objects are stored initially in Git.

You can see that [approach used elsewhere too (for images database for instance, actually on two levels](http://highscalability.com/blog/2012/6/20/ask-highscalability-how-do-i-organize-millions-of-images.html), but that applies for Git too):

> compute the SHA-1 hash of the image, generate its hexadecimal form, and use the first two characters of the SHA-1 string as a first-level directory.
>
> SHA1 hashes give good distribution, even in the first few characters, so that will nicely distribute the files into a (relatively) balanced folder structure.
>   This simplistic approach will use no more than 256 folders at each level.
>
> Using the hexadecimal form of the image's SHA-1 has two very nice benefits:
>
> - no name collisions, and
> - any given file will only be stored once even if the same file is uploaded more than once.

See [`gitrepository-layout`](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitrepository-layout):

### `objects/[0-9a-f][0-9a-f]`

> A newly created object is stored in its own file.
>   **The objects are splayed over 256 subdirectories using the first two characters of the sha1 object name to keep the number of directory entries in objects itself to a manageable number**.
>   Objects found here are often called unpacked (or loose) objects.

[git commit 88520ca](https://github.com/git/git/commit/88520cadf902c8bc780394e1ddecc726534c3df9) gives us more information about the benefit of that structure, which influences when `gc` is run:

> #### search 4 directories to improve statistic of `gc` hint
>
> On Windows, `git-gui` suggests running the garbage collector if it finds
>   1 or more files in `.git/objects/42` (as opposed to 8 files on other
>   platforms).
>   The probability of that happening if the repo contains about 100 loose objects is 32%.
>   The probability for the same to happen when searching 4 directories is only 8%, which is bit more reasonable.
>
> The following [octave script](https://www.gnu.org/software/octave/) shows the probability for at least `m*q`
>   objects to be found in `q` subdirectories of `.git/objects` if `n` is the
>   total number of objects.

(It uses the [Cumulative Distribution function (CDF)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cumulative_distribution_function) for [binomial distribution](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_distribution) [`binocdf`](https://www.gnu.org/software/octave/doc/interpreter/Distributions.html))

```
q = 4;
m = [1 2 8];
n = 0:10:2000;

P = zeros(length(n), length(m));
for k = 1:length(n)
        P(k, :) = 1-binocdf(q*m-1, n(k), q/(256-q));
end
plot(n, P);

n \ q   1       4
50      18%     1%
100     32%     8%
200     54%     39%
500     86%     96%
```

That organization also allows for [Git's packing heuristics](https://github.com/git/git/blob/398dd4bd039680ba98497fbedffa415a43583c16/Documentation/technical/pack-heuristics.txt) to be as quick and efficient as possible, when [`git gc` has to occur](https://github.com/git/git/blob/f53fc38c083da1a1d14f54713ffd8fd0965a2194/Documentation/git-gc.txt#L50-L55).

Comment: I think that packs are the files that git generates after a while in the .git/objects/pack folder. The OP is rather asking about the objects that are not yet packed (eg in .git/objects/e8 for example)

Comment: @edi9999 yes, the pack files are built from the objects buckets, hence the importance of a correct "fanout" of those objects.

Answer (score 5):

They are multiple reasons to store files using the following method:

```
00/f56c0de1c61fdb926e79e8a0a65bd12930c9
25/ec1c55bfb660548a6770238668c4b117d92f
5d/4b01d98f17a9ad9dd1526b49ba39b5aa37a1
63/6f740b6c284ce6685dc17d473a7360ace249
b1/066d178188dde110149a8422ab651b0ee615
b1/a2b7d02b7b0c43530677ab06235382a37e20
da/a3ee5e6b4b0d3255bfef95601890afd80709
```

The main reason is that you can be limited in the number of files you can store in a folder : Some (pretty old) file systems don't allow you to store more than 64k files inside a directory. This is quite a small amount if you coun't everything that git stores.

Also, because you use a hashing algorithm, you're almost sure that a folder won't have too many files : the files should be equally spread across the subfolders (at least when the number of files grow)

I also think that it could cause performance issues on some filesystems to have too many files in a folder (altough I'm not 100% sure of that)