# Loose Objects and TortoiseGit v Git

Tags: git, tortoisegit

I use **TortoiseGit** for my repositories but sometimes I right-click and select **Git GUI Here**. Why does it sometimes show this:

[image: Loose Objects]

I let it compress the database. But **TortoiseGit** is not mentioning anything about this.

Unlike similar questions I am asking why **Git GUI** raises a message about loose objects and **Tortoise Git** does not. Thus it is not exactly the same as the nominated duplicate question.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What are the "loose objects" that the Git GUI refers to?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5709687/what-are-the-loose-objects-that-the-git-gui-refers-to)

Comment: @Schwern I am not specifically asking what loose objects are. I am asking why Git GUI prompts me about them but TortoiseGit does not.

Comment: @AndrewTruckle the accepted answer doesn't contain anything about the difference between TortoiseGit and Git GUI. As such I would assume your question doesn't really revolve around this difference and is indeed a duplicate.

Comment: @Zeeker I accepted the answer because they were courteous enough to help. Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

"Loose objects" mean objects that are individual files on the filesystem rather than in more efficient packfiles. "Compress the database" probably means it'll run `git gc`. See also this answer to [What are the “loose objects” that the Git GUI refers to?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5710039/14660)

These days Git will, from time to time, clean them up for you by running garbage collection, [`git gc`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-gc). There's no need to prompt the user. This feels like Git GUI has a hold over from years ago when Git did not do its own garbage collection. My understanding is 2880 is a fairly low number of loose objects.

Check that you haven't inadvertently set `gc.auto` to 0 with `git config gc.auto`.

Comment: Technically, "loose" just means "not packed", not necessarily unreferenced. But yes, I think GitGUI is just being silly here. :-)

Comment: @torek Thanks, I've updated the answer and found a better answer.