# How to prevent Git Gui from showing "loose objects" message on startup?

Tags: git, ubuntu, git-gui

- Git Gui
- Os: Ubuntu
- Ruby on rails project

I am getting this confirmation every time  on program startup.

> This repository currently has approximately 2304 loose objects.

Will pressing 'yes' affect my project in anyways ?

[image: Link to issue screenshot]

Comment: Behind the scene, if you press "Yes" it runs [`git gc`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-gc).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What are the "loose objects" that the Git GUI refers to?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5709687/what-are-the-loose-objects-that-the-git-gui-refers-to)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[What are the "loose objects" that the Git GUI refers to?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5709687/385532) probably will answer this for you. Basically, just press the yes button.

> Loose objects are the simpler format. It is simply the compressed data
>   stored in a single file on disk. Every object written to a seperate
>   file.

Comment: Will pressing yes anyway affect my project ? @Matt

Comment: @AbhijithR Yes it will. [In a good way](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-gc). It will take up less space on your disk and improve git's performance. _"Users are encouraged to run this task on a regular basis within each repository to maintain good disk space utilization and good operating performance."_

Comment: Thankyou for your help